# Pasar valores de cajas dinámicas en javascript a un archivo php

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy intentando hacer que el usuario vaya añadiendo tantas cajas dinámicas como le hagan falta (por ejemplo cantidad de idiomas que sabe) y una vez añadidas que pase los valores a un archivo `PHP` para guardar en base de datos, etc. De momento me sobra con listar desde un archivo `PHP` todos los campos que haya añadido. El código es el siguiente lo que no sé hacer es como listar las cajas en php.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>formulario dinámico</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
      var $form = $("#my-dynamic-form");

      $('#add-field-button').click(function() {
        var $fieldset = $('<fieldset>');

        $('<input type="text" name="idioma[]">').appendTo($fieldset);
        $('<input type="text" name="leido[]">').appendTo($fieldset);
        $('<input type="text" name="escrito[]">').appendTo($fieldset);

        $fieldset.appendTo($form);
      });

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>


<h1>Ejemplo de formulario dinámico</h1>

<form id="my-dynamic-form" action="guardar_formulario.php" method="post">
<!-- <input name="fields[]" type="Submit" value="Guardar" >-->
<button type="Submit" value="Submit" class="boton">guardar</button>
</form>

<button id="add-field-button">
Agrega un campo
</button>

</body>
</html>
```

En el archivo guardar `formulario.php` quiero hacer la lista de todos los valores que se han introducido y he puesto esto pero no funciona, evidentemente está mal. Pueden ayudarme?

```
<?php
echo "idioma[]: " . $v11 = $_POST["idioma[]"];
echo "<br>";
echo "leido[]: " . $v11 = $_POST["leido[]"];
echo "<br>";    
echo "escrito[]: " . $v21 = $_POST["escrito[]"];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te recomiendo hacer es que como puede crear tantos inputs como el quiera, cada input que cree debe tener una clase en particular por ejemplo

```
<input type="text" class="dinamicos">
```

Cuando hagas el envio del formulario, puedes hacerlo por `ajax`. Recorrer todos los valores de los inputs que tengan esa clase.

```
var datos = [];
$('.dinamicos').each(function(i, obj) {

});
```

Donde el valor de `obj` es de cada uno de los inputs entonces en el arreglo `datos` puedes hacer `push` de un item el cual quieras con el formato que necesites. Y finalmente envias por `ajax` ese arreglo asi en php puedes recibirlos. Como veo que separas por tipos idioma, leido y escrito. Puedes hacer que cada input tenga una clase distinta.

```
 <input type="text" class="idioma">
 <input type="text" class="leido">
 <input type="text" class="escrito">
```

Haces los each correspondientes para cada clase

```
var idioma = [];
$('.idioma').each(function(i, obj) {
    idioma.push(obj);
});
var leido = [];
$('.leido').each(function(i, obj) {
    leido.push(obj);
});
var escrito = [];
$('.escrito').each(function(i, obj) {
    escrito.push(obj);
});
```

Asi tienes los 3 arreglos distintos y los envias a tu archivo php.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/guardar_formulario.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data : {'idioma' : idioma, 'leido' : leido, 'escrito' : escrito}
    success: function() {
              alert( "Funcionó" );
    },
    error: function() {
              alert( "Ha ocurrido un error" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cuando indicas que el `name` de un `input` es un arreglo, por ejemplo `idioma[]`, lo que sucede automáticamente es que la variable `idioma` sera enviada como un `array`, es decir, `idioma[0]=X0&idioma[1]=X1&idioma[2]=X2` y así sucesivamente.

Error:

Dentro de `POST`, las variables `"idioma[]", "leido[]" y "escrito[]"` no existen, pero si las `"idioma", "leido" y "escrito"` y el tipo de dato de estas sera un arreglo (`array`).

Solución:

```
<?php
echo "idioma[]: " . var_export($_POST["idioma"], true);
echo "<br>";
echo "leido[]: " . var_export($_POST["leido"], true);
echo "<br>";    
echo "escrito[]: " . var_export($_POST["escrito"], true);
?>
```

[Demo aquí](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/2wau-szpj)